# Regarding declaring array in c

Tags: c

Whenever I create an array in C using sublime text editor I get following error
[image]

The code written is:
[image]

Comment: Indeed, this question appears to be more suited to Stack Overflow, or perhaps one of the programming-themed sites. When you post your question there, it is likely it will be best received if you post your code as text rather than as pictures.

Answer (score 3):

Don't separate:

```
char a[4];
a[4] = {...};
```

Put it all on one line:

```
char a[4] = {...};
```